# Is it safe to use a uintptr as a weak reference

Tags: go, garbage-collection

I want to implement a weak reference in Go such that I can use a finalizer to detect when a data structure is no longer required and be able to store/clean up data.

One way I have found to do it is to use a uintptr as a map key such that when a finalizer is called, I can access/cleanup the data using the pointer value passed to the finalizer function. Is this safe to do?

I think my question is: does Go use a moving garbage collector?  Or will it?

Comment: Go is a language specification, and that specification makes no mention of garbage collection at all, except to mention in the introduction that Go is garbage-collected. This means there are literally _no guarantees_ about how garbage collection is done (and honestly, even _if_ it is done--there are some implementations that do not do GC at all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The link](https://groups.google.com/u/1/g/golang-nuts/c/1ItNOOj8yW8) that you yourself quoted [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63025066/is-it-safe-to-use-a-uintptr-as-a-weak-reference-in-go#comment111452643_63025239) provides the answer to the question you meant to ask: instead of giving clients a pointer to the underlying object that you'd like to fuss with, give them a pointer to a wrapper object:

```
type internal struct {
    // all the internal stuff goes here
}

// change the name Wrapper below to something more suitable
type Wrapper struct {
    *internal   // or p *internal if you want to be overly verbose
}

func NewWhatever(/*args*/) *Wrapper {
    p := &Wrapper{...} // fill this part in
    runtime.SetFinalizer(p, wrapperGotCollected)
    return p
}

func wrapperGotCollected(p *Wrapper) {
    // since p itself is about to be collected,
    // **p (or *((*p).p)) is no longer accessible by
    // the user who called NewWhatever().  Do
    // something appropriate here.
}
```

Note that this does *not* use a finalizer on the `*internal`, but rather a finalizer on the `*Wrapper`: at the time that `wrapperGotCollected` is called, the `*internal` object itself is guaranteed still to be live because `p` itself has not yet been GC-ed (it's sort of halfway there, and will be the rest of the way there as soon as, or shortly after, `wrapperGotCollected` returns).

Answer (score 2):

The [unsafe documentation](https://godoc.org/unsafe#Pointer) allows for GC that moves values in memory.

> A uintptr is an integer, not a reference. Converting a Pointer to a uintptr creates an integer value with no pointer semantics. Even if a uintptr holds the address of some object, the garbage collector will not update that uintptr's value if the object moves, nor will that uintptr keep the object from being reclaimed.

Comment: I'm using finalizer but I have a number of constraints I did not go into enough detail on.  Specifically I want to embed a pointer such that I can natively call its methods while atomically updating its value in the event of changes.   https://groups.google.com/u/1/g/golang-nuts/c/1ItNOOj8yW8 was the final clue I needed. You can embed pointers to pointers if they're wrapped in another struct type.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness this is what I wound up doing something like:

```
type actualThing struct {
    Data int
}

type internalHandle struct {
    *actualThing
}

type ExternalHandle struct {
   *internalHandle
}
```

So a user of `ExternalHandle` can still write code like `ExternalHandle.Data` but the internal maintenance code can still atomically update `*actualThing`.  A finalizer on a pointer to an `ExternalHandle` will signal the rest of the stack to delete references to `internalHandle` and stop propagating updates to it.

Basically the super convenient thing is that by nesting the structs as such, users of `ExternalHandle` use it without realizing or dealing with the fact that it's a double pointer dereference.

Answer (score 0):

Go right now is doesn't have a moving GC but there's no guarantee that it will stay this way forever. If you want to rely on this aspect, you can import [this library](https://github.com/go4org/unsafe-assume-no-moving-gc) made by one of Go contributors:

```
import _ "go4.org/unsafe/assume-no-moving-gc"
```

It will crash your program if Go ever switches to a moving GC.